# ubuntu 20.04 does not connect using vpnc, but version 19.10 connected without problems. how to solve it?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, 20.04, vpnc

I have installed network-manager-vpnc-gnome, network-manager-vpnc, vpnc and configured the vpn like I did in ubuntu 19.10, but in 20.04 the same configuration doesn't work.

the tentative of connection returns this log in syslog:

```
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111298.1704] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535" name="AMC" pid=2142 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111298.1904] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 5416
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111298.2069] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111298.3074] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111298.3074] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111298.3145] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/14)
Apr 28 19:01:38 aspire5 systemd-udevd[5432]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 NetworkManager[5416]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: authentication unsuccessful
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 gnome-shell[2142]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111299.7015] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN plugin: failed: login-failed (0)
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111299.7017] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111299.7017] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111299.7019] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 28 19:01:39 aspire5 NetworkManager[930]:   [1588111299.7063] vpn-connection[0x55cdd7ee8590,760a60f1-ad7c-4e89-b6b1-915af7cd8535,"AMC",0]: VPN service disappeared
Apr 28 19:01:49 aspire5 systemd-resolved[836]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

I have been searching for a solution, but until now I couldn't find nothing.
I would appreciate an help in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution error NXDOMAIN:

```
mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.OLD
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Comment: After do this and call to the support of my company. it's work.. thank you.

Comment: That didn't change anything. Would be nice to know, what you suggestion is actually changing.